# Rip CD as one mp3 at 320 bitrate using Exact Audio Copy

Tags: exact-audio-copy

I can do individual tracks at 320 using the compression settings.
However, when I try to rip a CD as one track(i.e. compressed image), it's always something less than 320.
There seems to be no setting to force that at 320 (aside from ripping to WAV then converting via foobar or something).

Is there a setting for that?  Why is it less?

(using Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

mp3 isn't an exact copy.  It has compression which removes what isn't considered essential to the sound.  If you want an exact copy of the CD then just rip it to the flac format - that *is* lossless.

Other than that please edit your question to include the names of your operating system and the ripping software.

Comment: Exact Audio Copy is the software...question goes to those who use it...one can rip 320 on individual tracks, but not full CD.

Comment: Exact Audio Copy is the name of the software! :) It's in the tag as well. OP never implied it was intended for an "exact copy".